# How to change the name of your program in C# when clicking and dragging up from the taskbar?

Tags: c#, windows-7, taskbar

Ok. So in windows 7 you know how you have the icons of open programs. Well when i click and drag up on my C# Windows Form application it says "WindowsFormApplication3" When in every possible file in Visual Studio i changed it to the name of my program. And even in task manager it shows my name of the program. How can i change this name that shows when clicking and dragging up from my programs icon in the taskbar?

Answer (score 2):

It is normally based on the process name.  Verify this with TaskMgr.exe, Processes tab and check that it is called "WindowsFormApplication3" there as well.

You change it with Project + Properties, Application tab, Assembly name setting.

Comment: Thank you, however, under windows task manager it lists it as "MyProgram.exe" (what i named it) as well as under Project properties application tab it is also listed "MyProgram" 

Now, i did change the assembly name setting partway through the writing of the program. Could that have been the reason why its not changing?

Comment: Well, that makes it harder to explain.  Did you change the icon of the app as well?  Check this by running the app on another machine to make sure you are not chasing the infamous shell icon cache ghost.

Comment: Actually yes i did change the icon within Visual Studio..

Comment: I dont understand how or why this question was closed as its a serious issue and i HAVE done everything RIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program outside of the debugger. Press [ctrl]+F5 to do this, and see what it is called then. The name shown when you run it outside the IDE debugger should be what shows when someone else would run your program AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, but it says WindowsFormsApplication3 i already had it running outside the debugger. I just cant figure out what file holds this information.